# What's the best clamp for a hex shape?

Tags: technique

I was using a round punch to pound a nail through wood in a confined space, and tried using a locking wrench or vise grips on the hexagonal steel handle of the punch, to keep from hitting my hand, but nothing is quite preventing me from knocking the punch through those clamps. They're good enough for one nail, but I have to readjust them afterward.  Just wondering if there's another clamp strong enough to hold a chisel style handle that you're basically trying to pound through it.

By the way, I've since tried wrapping a few layers of duct tape around the hex handle, behind where the clamp is over it, and that prevented the clamp from sliding backwards, or at least it won't happen as frequently this way. Let's see, after hitting a few more nails in, it seems that the clamp will be forced to the end of the punch, no matter what, although the hammer striking its end keeps the tape from going any farther, so I guess the tape will compress as much as possible while staying even with the end, or eventually fold upwards. Maybe it will last for a box of nails though.

I was also thinking of hand guards, like some chisels have, although they aren't as common on punches (or not widely available that way). Some are interchangeable however. It just depends on how much room there is to use one.

[image]

Comment: If you have one and space allows a small C-clamp/G-clamp may do it. C-clamps can exert immense force when cranked way down and used directly metal to metal the grip can be incredibly strong. I've relied on this a few times to clamp a chisel blade while knocking off the handle.

Comment: Thanks, I did try a C-clamp before the tape, and cranked it down real good, but it acted like a slingshot, because it didn't wrap around the sides of the punch like my wrench.

Comment: This may mark the punch, but vise-grip style pliers may do the job.  A long shot would be to try a tap wrench (used in cutting metal threads) if you have one.

Comment: Thanks, I tried vise grips too, which did clamp harder, because those bite into the metal, but they also took some of that metal away, when the punch pounded out of them. I don't have the v-jaw style though. I thought it was strange how these tools had a hex shape without a specific tool for holding that, but it looks like it is there to fit in a jackhammer or other power tool, from what I looked up.

Answer (score 1):

You can see examples at McMaster-Carr, search on punch and chisel holders. There are several styles shown

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought to look up a punch or chisel holder (after reading that they were designed to fit into jackhammers). Although those threaded hand tools get mixed reviews, so maybe it isn't necessarily the best clamp, by shape alone, or anything that gets pounded on could break, being that chisels are made for breaking things. Good to know though.